# How to get an assembly containing interface without Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I have a C# WinForms application and two assemblies involved - first contains an interface, second contains class which implements that inteface.

Application loads second assembly (via MS Enterprise Library Unity - i. e. via Reflection) and calls class methods.

I need to log that fact and before I was using the following code

```
var ApplicationInfo = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().ToString();
var InterfaceInfo = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().ToString();
var ImplementationInfo = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ToString();
```

It was working correctly some time ago (it obtained application, first assembly and second assembly respectively).

But now for some reason `GetCallingAssembly()` and `GetExecutingAssembly()` both return second assembly (containing class inplementation).

Is there a way to get an assembly containing interface without `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()`?

Any idea why `GetCallingAssembly()` started to be equal `GetExecutingAssembly()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a type in the current assembly implementing the interface then the definition has to be loaded. With a type definition you can get an assembly reference:

```
var asm = typeof(IInterface).Assembly;
```

If you have an instance (eg. created dynamically) then:

```
var asm = theObject.GetType().Assembly;
```